# Do we really need the "read-only" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've just stumbled upon the [read-only](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/read-only), used by 11 questions. My first evil idea was adding a [want-write](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/want-write) (which I of course didn't do). So I'm asking for a consent here: IMHO that tag should be burnitated.<sup>**1**</sup> Opinions?

---

<sup>**1:**</sup> For those who've not yet heard the term "burnitate", two hints here:

- [What does it mean to “burninate” a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/192154)
- [image: official BurnitatedDragon]
  <sup>The official "burnitated dragon"</sup>

Comment: Most likely it won't be Android specific if a question uses that tag. Although, if someone has problems with `/system` (or `/sdcard` on KitKat), they might need that tag then.

Comment: Then this fact IMHO should be part of the question body, not a tag. The proper tag is "file-system". Otherwise we end up with "mobile-data" + "offline", "contacts" + "invisible", "keyboard" + "not-responding" and other "useful" combinations ;)

Comment: I agree. Those are very useful combinations :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO it's useless. As you (@Izzy) said, the [file-system](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system) is the appropriate one for this situation, preferably with a clarifying clause in the question body (or, even better, in the title).

That's not to mention this tag ([read-only](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/read-only)) is nowadays a total misnomer except when it comes to the ARM TrustZone TPM chip firmware, which is (hopefully) burnt-in. Nearly nothing nowadays is really read-only with the correct tools.

This tag should be done away with at the earliest.

P.S.: What does "burnitated" mean?

Comment: [What does it mean to “burninate” a tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/192154). Added that to my question, including related graphic :)

Comment: Agreed with this.  I have removed the tag.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewRead – I've added the `status-completed` for that (that's how it should be, right? Please correct me if I was wrong with this ;)

Comment: @Izzy You are correct sir.